# find the shortest path between two points in a circular list in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list like the following :
`a =[1,2,3,4]`

The list is a circular list.
The **values in the list does not represent nodes**,but the index of the list represent nodes.
So the list may contain duplicated elements.
example,

```
if i take index (1,3)
(ie source is at index 1,and destination is at index 3) .
the shortest path is 1->4

if i take index (0,2) , i get two shortest paths
 1->2->3 and 
 1->4->3
```

How may i proceed this in python?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Here's one thing to consider: *in a list without duplicates*, the shortest path between two points in your circular list is equal to the smaller of (a) the shortest path that doesn't "loop", and (b) the shortest path that does.  You should be able to extend this logic to handle the case where node can be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks that this is what you want:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a = L[1]
b = L[3]
cnt1 = []
cnt2 = []
for x in range(L.index(a), L.index(b) + 1):
    cnt1.append(L[x])
for x in range(L.index(a), L.index(b) -(len(L) + 1), -1):
    cnt2.append(L[x])

if len(cnt1) <= len(cnt2):
    print(cnt1)
else:
    print(cnt2)
```